# MDI application with outlook interface like display winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi

I have an MDI applicaiton working fine, now I want to display a DASHBOARD displaying 4-5 Grid controls where data is populating using workerbackground thread so far so good.

The requirement is that the Dashboard must stay on the background on the main parent form always becuase its receiveing live data.

Now when I am trying to display this user control (Dashboard) I am unable to show any child forms because this is MDI applcaiton.

please is there any way that I can display my Dashboard usercontrol in the parent form and also the child forms, when ever required.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to make it look like Outlook, that's not an MDI app.  Anything you put on the MDI Parent must be docked to an edge.  The dark gray MDI client window shrinks accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you show the Dashboard user control in a MDI child form as well?  You can rig that specific form not to have the control buttons (to prevent user from closing it) and not to be resizable, so that the application remains in control of it position.

I assume that the user never really needs to interact with it, so you will also have to prevent it from getting focus, because that will hide all the other MDI forms.